# How to loop mount an sdcard image in Android, not on the device/emulator

Tags: android, gem5

I am using an ARM full-system simulator (gem5) to run Gingerbread. The Gingerbread image was obtained from the gem5 website, but it is a standard. 
Most apps of my interest need an sdcard, so I added "mount -o loop /system/sdcard " to the init.rc file on my Android image. When I boot the simulated system, the applications complain about sdcard not being present on the system. 
Does Gingerbread's mount (from toolbox or busybox) support loop mounting image files? 
Going by [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1164344) link, it seems the busybox version used by Gingerbread does have an issue with loop mounting, but I cannot make out if that is the sole issue. If so, how do I replace the busybox version on an Android filesystem? Can I just replace the busybox binary with a newer one?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you already have a vfat partition image like `/sdcard.img`, in init.rc you can try adding this:
`mount vfat loop@/sdcard.img /mnt/sdcard`

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/ipaq214android/blog/2012/05/mounting-loopback-device-by-initrc/